# CSS line-break issue

Tags: css

I searched the forum for a similar CSS issue but my keywords didn't really help. I apologize if this has been asked elsewhere but I couldn't find it.

So, to be brief, I'm new to website design and am trying to build a site for a friend. I have an idea laid out and am putting it together bit by bit, but I ran into a strange issue. It's difficult to explain so I'll post two links and explain the difference between the two:

[Link1](http://vinylwines.com/ac_new/index1.php) and 
[Link2](http://vinylwines.com/ac_new/index2.php)

The problem I'm having should be clear if you look at the two sites. Basically, I have a "content" section that seems to have some invisible tag invading it for the first two lines. The only difference between the two references above is that on the first, I put a < p > tag in the "content" section, and on the second, I put two line breaks and then the < p > tag. The fact that the text wraps when there are two line breaks but not otherwise suggests to me that there is some DOM element invading the "content" div's space, but I have used every browsers' "inspect" tool and cannot find the culprit. If anybody can assist me, I'd greatly appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: Try to find out here : http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/css-layouts/

Comment: I've looked at that site quite a bit. I've studied CSS a lot and actually know a decent amount about it but the issue I'm running into is foreign to me. Generally, if I have an issue like this, I can use FireBug or a browsers' built-in debugger to find my problem but this time nothing seems to be helping :(

Comment: What is the wrapping you are talking about? How does the word “Test” wrap?

Comment: I suppose "wrap" is the wrong term. Basically, in the first example above, the word "test" is way off to the right but with a couple of line breaks, it moves it to the left, where it should be. This suggests there's something "in its way" causing it to be to the right initially but then move down with the line breaks, below whatever was blocking it, and end up on the left, where I want it to be. I hope this helps.

Comment: try overflow:auto; or clear:both for #content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at your code and it needs some rethinking and restructuring. Your use of css positions is not appropriate. Please dig deep into positioning and floats to understand better on how to structure your containers.

To fix your issue, you can add `clear: both` on `#content`

```
#content{clear:both;}
```

Comment: I was hoping I could add a check for both this post and the above, as they both worked, but I wasn't allowed to. The "overflow:auto" and "clear:both" suggestions both worked but I am a little confused at to why this is the case. You said my use of css positions isn't appropriate and I'd like to know why this is. The only positioning I used was to put the necessary spacing between the "sections" and the background image. Is there a better way to do this? And even if there is, I don't understand why I needed to clear floats in order for the content to be displayed correctly...

Comment: the content div is separated from the others and I haven't used any "absolute" or "fixed" positioning. Maybe my understanding of "floats" is what needs revision. I've read a ton of CSS articles to help explain positioning and floats and I thought I understood it(them), but apparently I don't. I really don't get why "clear: both" works when there should be no floats invading the "content" div.

Comment: I think it's more subjective what you decide to use to separate the containers. May be 'not appropriate' was not the right word. I would have just let the divs stack naturally and may be use margins to create the spacing.

You were using float on logo and navbar. Than elements after it were not using floats. So, it was getting kind of messed up. Usually, if you are using floats for certain containers and decide to not use floats for following containers, you might want to clear those floats, as I did with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In first link (without line breaks, remove   top:25px add     overfolw:auto)

```
#content {
background: white;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 550px;
margin: auto;
opacity: 0;
overflow: auto;
}
```